# Add SQL check keyword in django model

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model with a list of choices:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
  CHANGE_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        ("creation", "Création"),
        ("modification", "Modification")
    )
    change_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=128, choices=CHANGE_TYPE_CHOICE
    )
```

Unfortunately, another app need top have access to this SQL table. I'd like to add a SQL CHECK (since using enum in django seems to be overly complex) is there a way of providing specific field db creation or do I have to do it manually on the db side?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/ didn't help me much.

Comment: But what will you do by adding `CHECK` constraint? These are added in conditions like age>18 etc.

Comment: Something like change_type IN ('foo', 'bar')